# How to Order Name without Prefix Name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have table like this.
I want to return customers_name and sort customers_name column by ascending (A to Z), however the prefix name should not be part of the order.
Example: Ir. Finna Nugraha must be above Heidi Gohms.

| ms_customer |
| --- |
| Field |
| no. |
| customers_id |
| customers_name |
| address |

| customers_name |
| --- |
| August Neight |
| Denny Smith, Dr. |
| Eva Novianta, S.H. |
| Heidi Gohms |
| Ir. Finna Nugraha |
| Irquan Abdullah |
| John Haambt |
| Maria Sirnat |
| Tommy Santos |
| Ugame Konogawa |

Answer (score 3):

You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove the leading prefix while sorting:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ms_customer
ORDER BY REGEXP_REPLACE(customers_name, '^\w+\.\s+', '');
```

If you are using a version of MySQL earlier than 8+, then we can try the following workaround:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ms_customer
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN customers_name REGEXP '^\w+\.\s+'
         THEN SUBSTRING(customers_name, INSTR(customers_name, ' ') + 1)
         ELSE customers_name END;
```

Comment: Cannot use REGEXP_REPLACE "ERROR 1370 (42000) at line 2: execute command denied to user"

Comment: @JosephArmandoCarvallo You're probably using an earlier version of MySQL.  I have given you a workaround in this case.

Comment: Can I ask what '^\w+\.\s+' is?

Comment: It is a regex pattern which matches a word at the start of the customer name which also ends in a dot.  This would match any customer names having the prefix.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know REGEXP syntax before